# Можно ли в js отловить событие окончания загрузки файла?

Tags: apache, сервер, javascript

Можно ли в js отловить событие окончания загрузки файла с сервера после клика по ссылке на него?

`<a href="http://mydomen.com/files/file.doc">`, например.

Или тогда настроить апач чтобы он удалял файл после отдачи?

Comment: интересно зачем?

Comment: Очень сомневаюсь. Разве что посредством каких-нибудь ActiveX, да и то навряд ли

Answer (score 1):

Через AJAX - вполне можно, в новых редакциях чего только нет.
А напрямую через браузер - нет (с этим связана большая проблема загрузки и выполнения JS-файлов). Хотя поизвращаться никто не запрещал, но стоит ли это делать?